# Encapsulation and constraining in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, encapsulation

I have this test program:

```
class BankAccount:
     def __init__(self, name, balance):
         self.name = name
         self.balance = balance
         self.transaction_fee = 5.00
     def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance + amount
     def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
```

I encapsulated the balance, name and transaction fee by doing the below:

```
class BankAccount:
     def __init__(self, name, balance):
         self._name = name
         self._balance = balance
         self._transaction_fee = 5.00
     def deposit(self, amount):
        self._balance = self._balance + amount
     def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
```

Now I need to modify the BankAccount class to enforce the invariant that the account’s balance cannot ever become negative. This means that you should forbid negative deposits and forbid withdrawals that are more than the balance on the account.

I had thought to use a if/else statement in the deposit and withdraw function. For example:

```
 def deposit(self, amount):
    if amount >= 0:
          self._balance = self._balance + amount
    else ?????
```

The else part, I am not sure how to make it go back to the function and ask again for a proper value.

Is there another way to accomplish this too?

Thanks

Comment: If you enforce non-negative amounts in the `deposit()` method then you don't need the `else:`. If you enforce this outside `deposit()` then you *can* do something about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your methods, you could return a Boolean indicating success or failure. Then the calling code can deal with it appropriately.

If you are worried that the calling code might ignore the return value and the transaction silently fail, you could raise an exception instead and leave the calling code to deal with that - something like this:

```
class BankAccount:
     def __init__(self, name, balance):
         self._name = name
         self._balance = balance
         self._transaction_fee = 5.00
     def deposit(self, amount):
        if (self._balance + amount) < 0:
            raise Exception("Balance cannot go below 0.")
        else:
            self._balance = self._balance + amount
     def withdraw(self, amount):
        if (self._balance - amount) < 0:
            raise Exception("Balance cannot go below 0.")
        else:
            self._balance = self._balance - amount
```

In real life you would create your own subclass of Exception and raise that.

Answer (score 1):

One way of dealing with this would be defining an exception class for this module (e.g. `AccountError`) and raising that exception in case someone tries to deposit a negative amount (or do anything else that is not allowed).

In the place where the `deposit()` method gets called, you could then catch the exception (with help of a `try`-`except`-block) and allow the user to retry if they entered an invalid value.

It might look like this:

```python
class AccountError(Exception):
    """Module specific error"""


class BankAccount:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount >= 0:
            self._balance = self._balance + amount
        else:
            raise AccountError("Deposit amount cannot be negative")
```

(You can add more information and functionality to the exception, of course.)

And in the place where the code gets called:

```
account = BankAccount()
...
...
try:
    account.deposit(negative_amount)
except AccountError as exc:
    # Code that allows you to retry the deposit.
    # Implementation depends on your program structure.
```

The whole block could be embedded inside a `for` or `while` loop with a certain amount of retries, or whatever makes sense in you case.

The specific implementation will depend on how your program is structured and what it does.